# Update formGroup values if value is empty

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have an angular project that has a form with a variating amount of form controls. This is how my template looks:

```
<form [formGroup]="updateValuesForm">
   <div *ngFor="let controlName of updateValuesForm.controls | keys">
      <input [formControlName]=controlName type="text">
   </div>
</form>
```

This works as expected. I am now trying to implement the following:
If a control value is empty, the value should be changed to `&nbsp;`, this value should not be shown in the form (as endusers would not understand what this would mean). Is this even possible in Angular forms?

Comment: Cann't you do that the moment of submit or when you need it for some 'manipulation', just if(!this....controlName.value) val=""&nbsp;" and use val instead. I am thinking why would you want to change the value if you don't use it and don't display either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, instead of changing the value of the input when it's empty, simply change the value of the data before it is handled when the form is submitted.  This will ensure the user does not see the `&nbsp;`.

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="updateValuesForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(updateValuesForm.value)">
    <div *ngFor="let controlName of updateValuesForm.controls | keys">
       <input [formControlName]=controlName type="text">
    </div>
</form>
```

**Typescript**

```
submitForm(data: any) {

    for (var value in data) {
        if (!data[value]) {
            data[value] = '&nbsp;';
        }
    }

    // Handle Form Submission

}
```